# Fail a procedure when error occurs in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would like my procedure to fail with a critical error when a certain error occurs. I have the below try catch block as part of it.
`

```
    BEGIN TRY 
    BEGIN
    some other sql ops
    END
    END TRY 
    BEGIN CATCH
    Declare @MESSAGE NVARCHAR(400) = N'Warning : some message'
    THROW 52000, @MESSAGE, 1;
    END CATCH`
```

Although the error is being captured as per the expectation and the process not going any further, the procedure is not ending with a critical failure instead says completed successfully. I need it to do so for my wrapper process to identify critical failure and perform relevant actions. I tried raise error and also with different severity so far but no luck.

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL; what are you *really* using? This *looks* like T-SQL, which suggests SQL Server.

Comment: @Larnu pardon my ignorance. Thank you. Im using SQL server.

Comment: *"the procedure is not ending with a critical failure instead says completed successfully"* where are you seeing that the process was "succesful"?

Comment: I have a test case that invokes this procedure as its last step. I deliberately setup the test case to hit the catch block mentioned in the procedure. When executed, I am hoping it would give me a critical failure.

Comment: So you are saying you *don't* get an error that states "Warning : some message"? Then the `CATCH` isn't being entered.

Comment: If I add some code in your `TRY` that generates an error (such as a divide by zero), I get the error as expected: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tESmxsvy) You need to provide a [mre] here that demonstrates that you have code that would error, however, does not enter the `CATCH`.

Comment: Severity is always set to 16 when you use `THROW` with a custom error message. Maybe you want to use `RAISERROR` instead, so you could at least try to see if setting a more severe severity will make your test suite behave.

Comment: @larnu the code block I provided is a sub process of a larger stored procedure. The test case is designed to duplicate reference data to the procedure and this code snippet I provided in actuality has several DML operations in the begin end block that does not output transactions with duplicate reference data. The test case also fabricates 2 transactions. The output of the procedure is expected to be 2 records if the catch block is not being invoked. But my result shows 1 record as per the expectation. I may not be handling output to display this message but catch block is definitely invoked.

Comment: That's why I asked for an [mre] @KahLeon . We can't see your code so you need to give an actual working example of the code that isn't working as you expect, as describe what you were expecting to happen.

Comment: Be careful here. You have created an anti-pattern I call try/squelch. You set up a try/catch block but in the catch you don't provide any details about the error which makes it impossible to debug or understand why the error occurred. Maybe your code here is a just a snippet to provide context but if this is the actual code I would suggest doing something with the error. Log it, return the error message, something to help fix the problem when it does happen.